# Is it true that $\langle [x]\rangle +\langle [y]\rangle =\mathbb Z_n?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

> Consider the ring $\mathbb Z_n$ where $n=p^a q^b$.
>   Let $[x]\in \langle [p]\rangle \setminus \langle [pq]\rangle$ and $[y]\in \langle [q]\rangle \setminus \langle [pq]\rangle$ where $\langle [p]\rangle $ denotes the ideal generated by $[p]\in \mathbb Z_n$.
>   Here $p<q$ are primes.
>
> Is it true that $\langle [x]\rangle +\langle [y]\rangle =\mathbb Z_n?$

**My try**::

$[x]\in \langle [p]\rangle \setminus \langle [pq]\rangle\implies [x]=s[p]$ and $[y]\in \langle [q]\rangle \setminus \langle [pq]\rangle\implies [y]=t[q]$.

Also $[x]\notin \langle [pq]\rangle\implies \gcd(s,q)=1$. Also $\gcd(t,p)=1$.

Is it true that  $\langle [x]\rangle +\langle [y]\rangle =\mathbb Z_n?$

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do we have $p\neq q$?

Comment: @Arthur; question edited

Comment: @Arthur; can u help now?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ By Euclid and $\, (p,q) = (t,p) = (s,q)  = 1\ $ we have in $\Bbb Z$
$$\begin{align}
(sp+tq,\,p)\ \  &=\, (tq,p)\, = (t,p)=1\\[.2em]
 (sp+tq,\,q)\ \  &=\, (sp,q) = (s,q)=1\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ (sp+tq,\,p^aq^b)&=\,1\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: Why is $(s,p)=1$?

Comment: @Math_Freak It was a typo, meant to be $(s,q),\,$ now fixed. Please ask questions *before* downvoting (and always feel free to fix obvious typos).